# pyspark corr for each group in DF (more than 5K columns)

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DF with 100 million rows and 5000+ columns. I am trying to find the corr between colx and remaining 5000+ columns.

```
aggList1 =  [mean(col).alias(col + '_m') for col in df.columns]  #exclude keys
df21= df.groupBy('key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4').agg(*aggList1)
df = df.join(broadcast(df21),['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']))
df= df.select([func.round((func.col(colmd) - func.col(colmd + '_m')), 8).alias(colmd)\
                     for colmd in all5Kcolumns])


aggCols= [corr(colx, col).alias(col) for col in colsall5K]
df2 = df.groupBy('key1', 'key2', 'key3').agg(*aggCols)
```

Right now it is not working because of spark 64KB codegen issue (even spark 2.2). So i am looping for each 300 columns and merging all at the end. But it is taking more than 30 hours in a cluster with 40 nodes (10 core each and each node with 100GB). Any help to tune this?

Below things already tried
- Re partition DF to 10,000
- Checkpoint in each loop
- cache in each loop

Comment: Groups can vary from 100 rows to 5-10 million,  number of groups will be 7000.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with a bit of NumPy and RDDs. First a bunch of imports:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import numpy as np
from pyspark.statcounter import StatCounter
```

Let's define a few variables:

```
keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"] # list of key column names
xs = ["x1", "x2", "x3"]    # list of column names to compare
y = "y"                         # name of the reference column
```

And some helpers:

```
def as_pair(keys, y, xs):
    """ Given key names, y name, and xs names
    return a tuple of key, array-of-values"""
    key = itemgetter(*keys)
    value = itemgetter(y, * xs)  # Python 3 syntax

    def as_pair_(row):
        return key(row), np.array(value(row))
    return as_pair_

def init(x):
    """ Init function for combineByKey
    Initialize new StatCounter and merge first value"""
    return StatCounter().merge(x)

def center(means):
    """Center a row value given a 
    dictionary of mean arrays
    """
    def center_(row):
        key, value = row
        return key, value - means[key]
    return center_

def prod(arr):
    return arr[0] * arr[1:]

def corr(stddev_prods):
    """Scale the row to get 1 stddev 
    given a dictionary of stddevs
    """
    def corr_(row):
        key, value = row
        return key, value / stddev_prods[key]
    return corr_
```

and convert `DataFrame` to `RDD` of pairs:

```
pairs = df.rdd.map(as_pair(keys, y, xs))
```

Next let's compute statistics per group:

```
stats = (pairs
    .combineByKey(init, StatCounter.merge, StatCounter.mergeStats)
    .collectAsMap())

means = {k: v.mean() for k, v in stats.items()}
```

*Note*: With 5000 features and 7000 group there should no issue with keeping this structure in memory. With larger datasets you may have to use RDD and `join` but this will be slower.

Center the data:

```
centered = pairs.map(center(means))
```

Compute covariance:

```
covariance = (centered
    .mapValues(prod)
    .combineByKey(init, StatCounter.merge, StatCounter.mergeStats)
    .mapValues(StatCounter.mean))
```

And finally correlation:

```
stddev_prods = {k: prod(v.stdev()) for k, v in stats.items()}

correlations = covariance.map(corr(stddev_prods))
```

Example data:

```
df = sc.parallelize([
    ("a", "b", "c", 0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 1.0),
    ("a", "b", "c", 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, -2.0), 
    ("a", "b", "c", 1.5, 1.5, 2.9, 3.6),
    ("d", "e", "f", -3.0, 4.0, 5.0, -10.0),
    ("d", "e", "f", 15.0, -1.0, -5.0, 10.0),
]).toDF(["key1", "key2", "key3", "y", "x1", "x2", "x3"])
```

Results with `DataFrame`:

```
df.groupBy(*keys).agg(*[corr(y, x) for x in xs]).show()
```

```
+----+----+----+-----------+------------------+------------------+
|key1|key2|key3|corr(y, x1)|       corr(y, x2)|       corr(y, x3)|
+----+----+----+-----------+------------------+------------------+
|   d|   e|   f|       -1.0|              -1.0|               1.0|
|   a|   b|   c|        1.0|0.9972300220940342|0.6513360726920862|
+----+----+----+-----------+------------------+------------------+
```

and the method provided above:

```
correlations.collect()
```

```
[(('a', 'b', 'c'), array([ 1.        ,  0.99723002,  0.65133607])),
 (('d', 'e', 'f'), array([-1., -1.,  1.]))]
```

This solution, while a bit involved, is quite elastic and can be easily adjusted to handle different data distributions. It should be also possible to given further boost with JIT.